# Slow mysql with multiple cms

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel, expressionengine

My server is currently running multiple CMS' on the one phpmyadmin. We have an Expression Engine and Wordpress (with woocommerce) installed. In addition I have two custom databases for my own simple PHP pages

recently I have been experiencing a lot of MySQL timeouts ("MySQL has gone away"). I don't have any significant or notable traffic increases since installing the wordpress to the server.

**My question is that would running both of these systems on the one database system be causing this, or would it be something a bit more complex.**

Cheers

Comment: Can you give us some more detailed information about your server?

Comment: The server runs cpanel and is on a shared hosting server in Australia. It doesn't appear to be slow based on any website speed tests I can run. The Database is managed through PHPmyadmin. My provider [link](https://serversaurus.com.au/)

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to do with having multiple databases but bad queries in one of your applications that bring the whole database down. I suggest checking slow_query_log or monitoring your MySQL with some client like phpmyadmin to find slow and inefficient queries and fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident you don't have additional traffic and you haven't made extensive changes you need to look at external factors.

Since you are running on *shared* hosting then you need to consider all the sites that are running on the same database, not just your own.

If another site running on the same data server spikes in popularity or has poorly optimized MySQL *all* the sites hosted on that particular database server will suffer.

When I experience something like this in the past I've reached out to the hosting company and they've either moved me to a less-congested database server or throttled back the other user's site that was sucking up resources.

Comment: Thanks for this, this actually makes a lot of sense, especially as I don't have any admin ability on the phpmyadmin or in the shell. The provider only seems to suggest query caching should be enabled (which I am reluctant to do, as the website is constantly updated) and that I have inefficient queries running - which I cannot debug without the admin access to the database anyway. I think I'll just have to get them to move me. This all seemed to be happening when the root directory of the server was changed from "home/mysite" to "home1/mysite". Perhaps they moved me. Thanks again.